# Pull images from album & display them

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
//access the directory
$dir = dir('pics');

//build array of files in the directory
while (($pic = @$dir->read()) !== FALSE){
    $pics [$pic]= filesize('pics/'.$pic);
}

asort ($pics);

$txtfile=@fopen('txtfile.txt', 'w');

if ($txtfile === NULL) {
    throw new FileOpenException('txtfile.txt');
    //loop though and print each file as a link
    foreach ($pics as $name => $filesize){
        if ($name !="." && $name !=".."){
            echo "$filesize bytes <img src='pics/".$name."'/><br>";
            $result =@fwrite($txtfile, $name . "\r\n");
            if ($result === FALSE)
                throw new FileWriteException();
            }
    }
}

fclose($txtfile);

?>
```

This code snippet was given by a professor to use for a project we are working on but it is not working & prof doesn't seem to know much.

The codes is meant to pull images from an album and display them but nothing I do seems to work. The album is named pics and is in the same folder as everything else.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"This code snippet was given by a professor to use for a project we are working on but it is not working & prof doesn't seem to know much."* - I kind of beg to differ here. He/she probably did that on purpose in order for you to figure it out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No the code given was actually meant to work & when asked about it in class he goes "thats weird it should be working" & then changed subjects - disclaimer the original code included `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>` in the top of the code so I don't think he was the one who even wrote it.

Comment: *lol* fair enough then. What about http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - anything popping up?

Comment: @Fred-ii- not as far as I can tell. I added
 `error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);` 
to my php script. I am getting something that says 

"Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in (...) on line 60"

Comment: you're going to need to "Google that"; could be a permissions issue, could be anything.